# Best way to customize text resources per customer in Java

Tags: java, localization

I have a codebase that is used by multiple customers and uses text resources. Mainly the same text is used, in some cases the customer wants a customization to fit their environment. Currently this is done via a rather fragile and unflexible custom solution, and I would like to change this.

What would the simplest way to do this be? Can I use ResourceBundles and give every customer their own Locale (e.g. Resources_en.properties, Resources_en_customer1.properties, ...) or is this a bad idea?

Would be glad for any input, language level is Java 7.

Thanks!

Comment: Where are your customers' text resources currently stored ?

Comment: Currently they are also stored in .property-Files, with a custom framework that has the customer customization file hardcoded. If a Resource is found in this property file it is used, otherwise the base file is used.

The problem is that anytime you add a new customer, you have to extend this unflexible framework.

Comment: Each user has different values ? I don't really see the use case.. But I would use database to store those values and maybe load them at login time if there is not a big number of it..

Answer (score 0):

Better to use single bundle for a language. (Say For example: strings_en.properties, strings_fr.properties). [Here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-internationalization/resourcebundle.html) is an example of usage of Internationalization.